# What's the domain of $(\log_{\frac{1}{2}}{x})^x$?

Tags: functions, elementary-functions

What's the domain of $$(\log_{\frac{1}{2}}{x})^x$$
I know that for defining $\log_{a}{x}$, $x$ must be grater than zero ($x\gt 0$) and ($a\gt$ and $a\neq 1$) but I asked this question in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-domain-of-log_-frac-1-2-x-x) and everyone had different answers with no consensus.
Can you solve and explain it?

Comment: Logarithms to bases $\leq1$ are **sick**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the constraints:

1. the logarithm is well-defined for $x > 0$.
2. Every function of the form $f(x)^{g(x)}$ is well defined for:
   i.  a non-negative base *if $g(x)$ is not an integer*;
   ii. any real base when $g(x)$ is an integer.

Requirement 2.i boils down to solving $\log_{\frac12} x \geq 0$:
$$\log_{\frac12} x \geq 0 \implies -\frac{\ln x}{\ln2} \geq 0 \implies \ln x \leq 0 \implies x \leq 1.$$

The condition 2.ii allows us to pick any $x \in \mathbb Z$.

Putting these two conditions together with the first one, we have the system
$$\begin{cases} x > 0\\
x \leq 1 \lor x \in \mathbb Z
\end{cases}$$
which, solved, yields $\operatorname{dom} f = (0, 1] \cup \mathbb Z^+$.

Comment: why the log should be grater than or equal to zero?

Comment: @AlirezaGhaffari: Please see my edit, is it clearer now?

Comment: Yes that became really nice and correct. :)

Comment: I don't think 2 is quite right. It says that $0^{\text{negative}}$ is defined. Perhaps change 2.i to be about positive bases, 2.ii. to be about any nonzero base. And add 2.iii. to handle when $0$ is the base.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Understand and prove the following:

$$x>0\;\;\text{and also}\;\;\log_{\frac12}x>0\implies x<1$$

Comment: the log which has a base less than 1, is absolutely decreasing. So your logic will change to x<1.

Comment: Yup, that's correct

Comment: why the log should be grater than or equal to zero?

Comment: @user84413 I'd appreciate that **before** you edit one of my answers you please ask me: you changed my *correct* answer $\;x< 1\;$ into the *wrong* one $\;x>1\;$ .

Comment: @AlirezaGhaffari Because $\;a^x\;,\;\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ in general defined only for $\;a>0\;$ .

Comment: ,don't be angry with... :) but, $a^x$ is such that when x is not $x \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @AlirezaGhaffari His editing *still* is wrong. About the domain containing the naturals $\;\Bbb N\;$ : It is correct, though one could argue that a "domain" has to be an open connected subset of $\;\Bbb R\;$ (i.e., an open interval), as requested in topology and, thus, many time in calculus. Yet this depends on each author's preferance.

Comment: @Timbuc I am very sorry; you are right, and I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

To define the domain you must start from the more '' external'' function, that is the exponential, requiring:
$$
\log_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)\ge 0
$$
that you can write as:
$$
\dfrac{\log (x)}{\log(\frac{1}{2})}\ge 0
$$
since $\log(\frac{1}{2})<0$ and $\log (x)$ is a real number only if $x>0$, this give: $0<x\le 1$ that is the domain.

Comment: why the log should be grater than or equal to zero?

Comment: The exponetial function with real exponent has real values only if the basis is a positive number. ( $(-2)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not a real number).